# Should I create a fish-tape tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have earned the right to create tags but not comfortable doing it without some discussion or review from those who have been around much longer than I.   Hopefully asking here is useful.

Would it be useful to have a tag for questions about getting high and low voltage cable from one place to another through and along walls, conduits, underground, attics, soffits, dormers, crawl spaces, under sidewalks, and so on?  Or is that too specific?

If it would be useful should that tag be *fish-tape* or *wire-fishing* or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The tag *fish-tape* is too specific. In my experience (here and IRL), most people who have a fish tape already know what to do with it. The people who *don't* have a fish tape, don't even know the term.

The question then becomes: Is there a tag that would be reasonably intuitive that covers the general *process* of "getting high and low voltage cable from one place to another through and along walls, conduits, underground, attics, soffits, dormers, crawl spaces, under sidewalks, and so on."?

Comment: I'll edit the question to reflect your suggestions, and I'll edit your answer slightly so it answers the edited question.